# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException occurs from ProgressDialog

Tags: android-asynctask, progressdialog, illegalargumentexception

I've 10 apps which uses AsyncTasks. As you know i show progressdialog in asynctasks to show progress of the task. But there is a problem that i couldn't solve so far about progressdialog.

Here is one of my AsyncTask class (which is not in a other class);

```
public class GetBalanceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

Context context;
ProgressDialog pd;

public GetBakiyeAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    String userAgent = HttpHelper.getRandomUserAgent(context);
    return HttpHelper.post(PreferenceHelper.getBalanceQueryAPI(context), userAgent);

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "","Please wait...",true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        if (pd != null & pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
            pd = null;
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        pd = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (result != null & result.length() > 0) {
        Utils.doTask(result);
    } else {
        Utils.ShowToast(context,
                "An error has occurred, please try again.",
                STYLE_CONFIRM, LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

and the execption is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:381)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
   at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
   at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
   at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
   at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:268)
   at fragments.RuyalarFragment$getRuyalarAsyncTask.onPostExecute(GetBalanceAsyncTask.java:27)
   at fragments.RuyalarFragment$getRuyalarAsyncTask.onPostExecute(GetBalanceAsyncTask.java:1)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I've searched the solution almost everywhere but there is no working results. Most of answers contain use isFinishing, onDestroy or something like this but no body is sure which is working.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

**How to reproduce the bug:**

Enable this option on your device: **Settings -> Developer Options -> Don't keep Activities**.
Press Home button while the 'AsyncTask' is executing and the ProgressDialog is showing.
The Android OS will destroy an activity as soon as it is hidden. When onPostExecute is called the Activity will be in "finishing" state and the ProgressDialog will be not attached to Activity.

**How to fix it:**

Check for the activity state in your onPostExecute method.
Dismiss the ProgressDialog in onDestroy method. Otherwise, android.view.WindowLeaked exception will be thrown. This exception usually comes from dialogs that are still active when the activity is finishing.

try this code :

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

<...>

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (pDialog == null) {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(StartActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    pDialog.show();
}

private void dismissProgressDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    dismissProgressDialog();
    super.onDestroy();
}

class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showProgressDialog();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        doMoreStuff("internet");
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)
    {
        if (YourActivity.this.isDestroyed()) {
            return;
        }
        dismissProgressDialog();
        something(note);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the advice but the problem is that i create asynctasks as class not in a class. I've read tons of articles like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but really this question has many duplicates on SO.

The most comprehensive summary of solutions I've found is [here](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/).

Basically use a retained Fragment to connect your AsyncTask to the new Activity.